# PDT Eclipse searching path

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I have PHP project and I am using Zend Framework. There is a library folder with Zend Framework and Doctrine. I would like to have autocompletion for Zend Framework classes, but I don't want to have "todo" things in Tasks window and I don't want to show results from this directories when I am performing searching.

How to configure Eclipse for that? I am using Helios release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move these libs **out** of the project folder, then add them as external Libraries: `Project Properties -> PHP Include Path -> Libraries -> Add Library...`